# How to write output from iptables-save to a script?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I have these iptables rules

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.10 on Thu Oct  6 17:16:01 2011
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [22517:2222881]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [2:176]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [16961:69145734]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct  6 17:16:01 2011
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.10 on Thu Oct  6 17:16:01 2011
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [29:3325]
:INPUT ACCEPT [18:2668]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.245.0/24 -j MASQUERADE 
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct  6 17:16:01 2011
```

They are generated from `iptables-save`.

I would like to have these rules as iptables commands that I can launch in a script instead.

How do I "convert" these rules to iptables commands?

Comment: What is your final goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do know that you can apply the ruleset by `iptables-restore < yourrules.conf`?
add the `-c` option to restore all counters.

You can export the rules with `iptables-xml`

I found [this script](http://danieldg.net/info/iptables/mkscript) and it seems to do the job.